# use RSA private key generated in php to encrypt in c

Tags: php, c, encryption, openssl, private-key

I have a RSA Private Key generated with openssl_pkey_new() in php. I save this in a txt file. Is it posible to use that key for decryptin in c.
I tried this but with no success:

```
RSA *r = PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey("C:/xampp/htdocs/RSA/daten.txt", NULL, NULL, NULL);
resultDecrypt = RSA_private_decrypt( 128 /* resultEncrypt*/ , encrypted, decrypted, r, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);
printf("%d from decrypt: '%s'\n", resultDecrypt, decrypted);
RSA_free ( r );
```

Thanks!!

Comment: as long as the key's formatted properly. e.g. if the c func is expecting the raw bytes, then don't feed it base64-encoded text, then you should be able to use that key anywhere. a "php key" isn't any different than a "c key". it's all just aes.

Comment: This isn't related to the question itself, but I'm slightly worried that you're storing a private key into a text document. Any writing to the hard drive leaves an easy trace behind for an attacker.

Comment: @MarcB I dont quite understand what you mean. The txt file isnt base64-encoded. It contains only the private key as normal starting with -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY and ending with ----END RSA PRIVATE KEY. I also tryed with :`FILE *fp = fopen("C:/xampp/htdocs/RSA/daten.pem", "r");
 RSA *r = PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(fp, NULL, NULL, NULL);` that also didn't work

Comment: @Greg I#m just trying it out. It wont be lake that later. I'm new to RSA with openssl :-).

Comment: PEM is basically base64 with a header and a footer indicating what is in there.

Comment: I figured out that the reading is working. The problem is in the decryption, but I don't know what. When I use RSA_NOPADDING I get nothing printed out, if I use the other PADDINGS the function is returning -1. I encrypt with openssl_public_encrypt in php and its padding is OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING. Which header holds this kind of padding?

Comment: Now it is working the padding OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING is the same as RSA_PKCS1_PADDING. I forgot that I reloaded my php code and the encrypted string that I used in c was not the rigth one. Silly me ;-). Thanks a lot to every body!!!